# success() function is not called after an ajax get request

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a jquery ajax script like following:

```
     function FillCity() {
        var stateID = $("#ddlState").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Employee", "Index")',
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { state: stateID },
            async: true,
            processData: true,
            success: function (data) {
                alert("SSSS");
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    }
```

And I tried calling to Controller action method. The data is sending to the controller's action method and I am also receiving data from the controller.

But unfortunately, it calls up error function instead of success.

Please find the below controller method for the same.

```
  public ActionResult FillCity(int state)
    {
        var cities = subbuObject.Cities.Where(c=>c.StateID == state);
        return Json(cities, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: What error? Use your browser tools (Network tab) to determine the cause

Comment: `Action` name is `FillCity`..but in `ajax` call..`URL` looks different

Comment: Your action name and url action name must be same. Like : `@Url.Action("Employee", "FillCity")`

Comment: I have tried with the @Url.Action("Employee", "FillCity"), still i am getting Error message only

Comment: @Subbu..it should be `@Url.Action("FillCity", "Employee")`

Comment: @pawan..@Url.Action("Employee", "FillCity"), this action fires for me and giving result. But Success function not firing for me.

Comment: @Subbu, `@Url.Action("Employee", "FillCity")` cannot possibly work - it is calling the `Employee()` method of `FillCityController`. The question will be closed if you do not add the details of the error - use your browser tools

Comment: @Subbu..please check all `overloads` for `@Url.Action()` carefully

Comment: @Stephen Muecke ..Thanks a lot, I have tried but i didn't find any error.

Comment: Of course you have an error - it would not hit the `error` call back if you didn't. Use your browser tools (Network tab) to see the response

Comment: @ Stephen Muecke...I got the -- 404 Not Found.

Comment: Then your url is wrong

Comment: @ Stephen.. Thanks for your suggestion and help. Issue from LINQ query.  I have successfully changed the query, now it is working fine for me. Thanks for all your efforts.

Comment: Thanks for all the valuable suggestions and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few things to do :

1. Use `@Url.Action("FillCity", "Employee")`. You are doing it wrong by confusing the parameters. First is the name of the method from the controller and second parameter is the name of the controller.
2. In your Ajax call, `dataType` is telling jQuery what kind of response to expect.
   Expecting JSON, or XML, or HTML, etc....the default it for jQuery to try and figure it out.
3. You don't have to use

   ```
   async: true, // set to true by default    
   processData: true, // set to true by default
   ```

Controller:

```
public class EmployeeController: Controller
{
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult FillCity(int state)
        {
             var cities = subbuObject.Cities.Where(c=>c.StateID == state);
            return Json(cities , "application/json", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
}
```

Script:

```
 <script>
        function fillCity() {
            var stateID = $("#ddlState").val();

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("FillCity", "Employee")',
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { state: stateID },
            success: function (data) {
                alert("SSSS");
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, still not firing the success function.

Comment: @Subbu i will add sample for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am new to mvc, really not able to understand what is going wrong in that. Please help me.

Comment: @Subbu Your method name is `FillCity` and you are calling different url in Ajax?

Comment: @ Bhushan.. i have changed the url, still not working. '@Url.Action("Employee", "FillCity")'

Comment: @Subbu  Use this: @Url.Action("FillCity","Employee")'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88152/discussion-between-subbu-and-bhushan-firake).

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong `url` path for your controller `action` in `ajax` call. it should be:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("YourActionNamne", "YourControllerName")',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { state: stateID },
    async: true,
    processData: true,
    success: function (data) {
        alert("SSSS");
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

In your case `url` will be:

```
url: '@Url.Action("FillCity", "Employee")'
```

If you have `Areas` in your application then `url` will be:

```
url: '@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { Area = "AreaName" })',
```

Comment: if i remove data variable from function in success, alert box firing. if i place data variable in success function, alert box is not firing and control goes to error and firs up error alert box.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fillCity() {
        var stateID = $("#ddlState").val();

            $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("FillCity", "Employee")',
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { state: stateID },
            success: function (data) {
                alert("SSSS");
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult FillCity(int state)
    {
        var cities = subbuObject.Cities.Where(c=>c.StateID == state);
        return Json(cities, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```